# is there a bug with restart in edubuntu 12.04

Tags: edubuntu

After a clean install of **edubuntu 12.04** on an Acer AO531-h netbook, restart doesn't work. The process starts normally but just before it shuts down the netbook freezes and I have to force shut down. The command "**sudo reboot**" has the same problem. I have no issues with shut down, only with restart. I'm absolute beginner.

Netbook specs: **Acer, intel atom CPU N270 @1.60GHz, 1.05 GHz 0.98GB RAM**
Dual booting with windows xp. No problems with windows.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

1) Open the terminal and run this command to edit grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

2) Find this line in the file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

3) Change its value like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=bios"
```

4) Save the file

5) Update Grub by running this command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

6) Reboot your Netbook. Everything must be fine now.